# Is it possible to make the horizontal axis of this chart show an entire year?

Tags: google-sheets

[image: Chart in Question]

[image: No options]

There are no customization options for the horizontal axis, so I'm unsure how I can make the axis span an entire year even if there is not data on every day.

Here is the script that adds the relevant data to the spreadsheet, just incase that is relevant.

```
function submitData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("BookForm"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("BookData"); //Data Sheet
  var row=datasheet.getLastRow()+1;

  //Input Values
  var values = [[formSS.getRange("D3").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D4").getValue(),
                 0,
                 formSS.getRange("D5").getValue(),
                 "=C"+row+"/D"+row+]];
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 5).setValues(values);
}

function submitPageData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("PageForm"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("PageData"); //Data Sheet
  var booksheet = ss.getSheetByName("BookData"); //bookdata Sheet
  var now = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  var book = formSS.getRange("C2").getValue();
  var currentPage = formSS.getRange("C3").getValue();

  var date = formSS.getRange("C4").getValue();
  if (date == "")
    date = now;
  var nbPages = 0;
  //Input Values
  var row = booksheet.getLastRow();
  for(var done=false;row >0 || done==false; row--)
    {
      var testbook = booksheet.getRange("A"+row).getValue();
      if(testbook == book){
        done = true;
        nbPages = currentPage - booksheet.getRange("C"+row).getValue() ;
        booksheet.getRange("C"+row).setValue(currentPage);
      }
    }

  var values = [[book,
                 nbPages,
                 date]];
  if(nbPages>0)
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 3).setValues(values);
}
```

I tried searching but was unsuccessful, as most of the answers I found were either not relevant to google sheets or not relevant to my specific issue. It seems that the horizontal axis only has customization options if the data is a number, and dates seemingly don't

Comment: Maybe you could have a separate table (2 columns) with one column accommodating full range of year dates & second column to lookup values from your original data (limited dates). This new table will be the data range for the graph now...

Comment: What do you want the labels to look like? One per year? Or a range of each month?

Comment: @Daniel I basically want the horizontal axis to treat 0 as jan 1st and 1 as dec 31st. The data entered through the year would then plot the graph to show trends over the year.